# When does a program want to ensure that it is the creator of a file?

Tags: linux, files

From The Linux Programming Interface

> If **a program must ensure that it is the creator of a file**, then the  O_EXCL  flag should be used when calling open()

I was wondering when "a program must ensure that it is the creator of a file"?

Is it related to the cases when the program wants the owner of a file to be the effective ID of a process running the program?

For a given file, since we can modify the owner of a file, how can I find out the creator of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The O_EXCL flag, used in conjunction with the O_CREAT flag, means that if the file already exists, the `open` call will fail. If the file doesn't exist, an attempt will be made to create it and open it.

One use for this is to create a simple lock file. If multiple processes try to open the same file with the O_CREAT and O_EXCL flags, one will succeed and the rest will fail. Of course, if the file already exists, for example because a previous process exited without removing the file, *none* of the subsequent attempts will succeed, so this is not the most robust way to manage a lock.

Another use is to create a file for writing that the process is confident no other process will write to. You might use this if you were creating a file in `/tmp`, where lots of other processes are creating files with similar, possibly identical, names. The `mkstemp` function in glibc calls `open` with the O_CREAT and O_EXCL flags.

Unix/Linux don't record the creator of a file (there may be an audit record emitted if the OS supports it.)

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "lock file"? It seems to me that the program which creates a lock file should delete it before termination, so is a lock file not used for storing meaning data, but for some other purpose?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476166/what-is-lock-file

Comment: I'll quote from Wikipedia: lock files "are files whose contents are irrelevant (although often one will find the process identifier of the holder of the lock in the file) and whose sole purpose is to signal by their presence that some resource is locked. A lock file is often the best approach if the resource to be controlled is not a regular file at all, so using methods for locking files does not apply. For example, a lock file might govern access to ... higher level protocols like servers or database connections."